# Print Array if Condition Exists

Tags: php, javascript

I'm working on a printing a baseball team lineup, via php. I want to print a place holder for a missing Player 6 (or any missing position)

So if Player 1 -> Player 5 is OK print, NO Player #6 print place holder, Player 7 -> Player 9 is OK print. I tried to simplify the code. I have tried solving this every which way but I keep getting stuck.

```
CODE:

$rot        = array();
$pos        = array();
$jn             = array();

$x = 1;
// loads up the arrays from the db
while ( $rot[$x], $pos[$x], $jn[$x])= $r->fetch_row() ) {
$x++;
}

// counts the actual number of players in linuep
// used for validation and error display
$num_players = mysqli_num_rows($r);

// controls the lineup position
for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++){
    if($rot[$i] == $i) {
    //prints player             
$lineup .= "<div data-fp='" . $pos[$i] . "'>" .$jn[$i]. "</div>";
    } else {
        // prints place holder
        $text = "This Position needs to be filled before the next game.";
        $lineup .= "<div id='pid' data-rel='".$text."' data-fp='' data-pid='' data-jn='' title=''>x</div>";
    }
}
```

I also tried this to iterate through the array rot[] to find the matching position and print the line but it actually prints the holder repeatedly.

```
// controls the lineup position
for ($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++){

for ($i = 1; $i <= ($num_players+1); $i++) {
  if ($x == $i) {  
       //prints player              
        $lineup .= "<div data-fp='" . $pos[$i] . "'>" .$jn[$i]. "</div>";
    } else {
        // prints place holder
        $text = "This Position needs to be filled before the next game.";
        $lineup .= "<div id='pid' data-rel='".$text."' data-fp='' data-pid='' data-jn='' title=''>x</div>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use more descriptive variable names, $rot, $jn, $pos, $r don't tell anyone anything.

Comment: @thedaian: Oh, it's telling me something.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: This mixes the database logic with the output which makes it somewhat complex. How do you know that a player in line is missing? Why don't you create an array that is indexed by the player position? Wouldn't that be much easier to handle?

Comment: `while ( $rot[$x], $pos[$x], $jn[$x])= $r->fetch_row() ) {` -- looks broken to me...missing a closing parenthesis there.

Comment: what stealthyninja said, you are missing a ( after while.
I'm trying to figure out what you wanna do but if you could give a small description of what kind of data is $rot and $jn holding then it would be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think @hakre answered it. I am taking the db logic to an array, but then breaking out of it when a value did not exist that was needed, then I needed to come back to array to print the rest of the values. It is more of a logic question.  

Using isset() gives me the the true/false answer to execute the solution. if(pos) exists execute. else move on to something different.

Thanks to all that replied!

RG

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
# index all players by position while taking them from the database

$players = array();
while ( $row = $r->fetch_row() ) {
    list($rot, $pos, $jn) = $row;
    $players[$pos] = compact(array('rot', $pos, $jn);
}

...

# line-up players
for ($pos = 1; $pos <= 15; $pos++)
{
    $playerExists = isset($players[$pos]);

    if ($playerExists)
    {
       # do this ...
    }
    else
    {
       # do that ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating an array where all numerical elements are filled (i.e. you'll always have a 1 thru 15) and your mistake is in the
    if($rot[$i] == $i) {

When populating the arrays from the database, add this line:
    `$playertoid = array_flip($pos); # pos is the player number array?`

i.e.
    `while ( ($rot[$x], $pos[$x], $jn[$x])= $r->fetch_row() ) {
        $x++;
    }
    $playertoid = array_flip($pos);`

Now you've created a reverse lookup table where the index is the player number.

Replace the
    `if($rot[$i] == $i) {`
line with:
    `if (isset($playertoid[$i])) {`